# What does "sudo apt install -f" command do in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo, skype

I'm very new in the Linux world and I have found a guide to install Skype.

This are the commands to install Skype:

```
wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

I don't understand why should I use the last command "sudo apt install -f". What does this command do? I see that skype is installed even I don't use this command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The middle line installs a .deb package, but it requests other packages you have not specified. The -f option then installs the packages that are missing.

Answer (score 3):

### `sudo apt install -f`  'to fix broken dependencies'

The command line

```
sudo apt install -f
```

attempts to fix problems with broken dependencies between program packages.

This is explained in `man apt-get`, while the man page of the new version `apt` is not complete.

```
   -f, --fix-broken
       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
       This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
       to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
       specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
       is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
       itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
       system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
       so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
       using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages).
       Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
       situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```